# SpringBoot does not contain ElasticSearchRestHealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration anymore

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch

My app has Elasticsearch health check disabled like this:

```
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.elasticsearch.ElasticSearchRestHealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration;


@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {        
    ElasticSearchRestHealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration.class
})
public class MyApp
```

It works fine with SpringBoot `2.1.8.RELEASE`. But now I want to upgrade my app to SpringBoot 
 `2.2.2.RELEASE`. The problem is that SpringBoot `2.2.2.RELEASE` does not contain `ElasticSearchRestHealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration` class anymore.

How this situation can be handled? What should be used in SpringBoot `2.2.2.RELEASE` instead of `ElasticSearchRestHealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration` to turn Elasticsearch health check off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that starting from `2.2.0.RELEASE` we need to use `ElasticSearchRestHealthContributorAutoConfiguration` instead of `ElasticSearchRestHealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration` class.

As written in the [doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.2.0.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/elasticsearch/ElasticSearchRestHealthContributorAutoConfiguration.html) those classes are the auto-configuration for `ElasticsearchRestHealthIndicator` using the RestClient.

The rest remains the same

```
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.elasticsearch.ElasticSearchRestHealthContributorAutoConfiguration;

@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {ElasticSearchRestHealthContributorAutoConfiguration.class})
public class MyApp
```